# How to make a dropdown-menu and dropdown-toggle class that behaves like a select Form element

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need a dropdown menu that will change the label of the button / toggle like a `select` tag in HTML. How do I do that?

Adding some code for clarification, though dunno if it would help much. I know how to make a dropdown menu with Bootstrap. I know how to make a HTML form select button. What I'm trying to ask is how to combine those two. This is my dropdown menu code:

```
   <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
      Daily
      <span class = "caret"></span>
   </button>

   <ul class = "dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
      <li><a href = "#">Daily</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#">Weekly</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#">Monthly</a></li>
   </ul>
```

But with that code, the button's label wouldn't get changed when the option changed. I know if I want to change the label of the button, I would have to make it into a select button. And to make it into a simple select button, I will have to do it like this:

```
<select name="time_range">
  <option value="daily">Daily</option>
  <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
  <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
</select>
```

But I still want to retain the look and feel of Bootstrap dropdown menu.

Comment: Please provide with relevant code...

Comment: What do you mean? I know how to make a select button. I know how to make a drop down button with bootstrap. But I don't know how to combine them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Html

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <button id="dropdown-button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdownList">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dropdownList li').find("a").click(function(){

    $('#dropdown-button').html($(this).html());
  });
});
```

there are lot of other ways to accomplish..Hope this helps...[codepen link](http://codepen.io/amangalvedhekar/pen/yamEGK?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

## 2023 Update for bootstrap 5.3

You can emulate/create the same effect you want via using a radio button OR a checkbox:

```css
.dropdown-item > input[type="radio"]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

label.dropdown-item:has(input[type="radio"]:checked){
    background-color: var(--bs-dropdown-link-active-bg);
    color: var(--bs-dropdown-link-active-color);
}

label.dropdown-item:has(input[type="checkbox"]:checked) {
    background-color: var(--bs-dropdown-link-active-bg);
    color: var(--bs-dropdown-link-active-color);
}

.dropdown-item > input[type="checkbox"]{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Daily
   </button>

   <ul class = "dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
      <li>
        <label class="dropdown-item">
         <input type="radio" name="day" />
          Daily
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
          <label class="dropdown-item">
             <input type="radio" name="day" />
             Weekly
          </label>
       </li>
      <li>
          <label class="dropdown-item">
             <input type="radio" name="day" />
             Monthly
          </label>
      </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Daily  - Multiselect
   </button>

   <ul class = "dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
      <li>
        <label class="dropdown-item">
         <input type="checkbox" name="day" />
          Daily
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
          <label class="dropdown-item">
             <input type="checkbox" name="day" />
             Weekly
          </label>
       </li>
      <li>
          <label class="dropdown-item">
             <input type="checkbox" name="day" />
             Monthly
          </label>
      </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

The idea is to use either a radio for a single type select or a checkbox with a multi-type select. Each input has the same name and via css I hade the input.

Also, using CSS I can place the same color that bootstrap uses for links having `aria-current=true`. Therefore, you avoid using unessesary js for look & feel.

For older versions you need to use the approrpiate css variables for color.